# Reclaim disk space after DELETE of millions of rows from MySQL table

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

We have an analytics service that uses a MySQL DB. It performs statistical analysis on some audit-level information, and this information is fed into the service via a data ingestion pipeline (via Kafka + SNS + SQS) with a HIGH ingestion rate. Let's say the table into which this happens is called `audits`, and around 20 rows are created in this table every second.

We recently ran into storage issues where this table grew to 450 GB in size (our RDS instance had around 700 GB total space), and all the other tables combined were around 200 GB, which meant we now had only 50 GB of free space.

We decided that we don't want to store the audit records older than a year, so we decided to `DELETE` all records older than a year.

When I performed this activity, I cleared out almost 200 GB of data, but RDS still showed 50 GB free space. We consulted some DBA experts and they said that MySQL doesn't "physically" free the disk space back to the OS on `DELETE` operations, and we have to run `OPTIMIZE` on this table to achieve what we want.

Now, when we try to run `OPTIMIZE`, because it's a huge table with 2 compound indexes, it's taking forever. We ran it for one whole night and it still didn't finish. We had to abort it at the end.

I searched online in a few places including the MySQL community forum, and it seems like this kind of scenario means you have to create a new table altogether with only the required data and then drop the older table.
The problem that I see with this approach is the application-level complexity.
Let's say we introduced this table today (17 Nov) and all writes happen into this table. Now, when a customer asks for historical analysis of the last 1 month, I have to get 29 days of data from the old table and 1 day of data from the new table, do a merge and then serve it to the customer.

Does anyone know of any better way of solving this problem? Anything that doesn't require a long downtime and can be done periodically?
I say periodically because we had initially planned to write a cron that performs `DELETE` operations once a day for records older than a year. But we'll once again run into the same problem where our deleted records still occupy disk space. So we would prefer something that can be done periodically.

Thank you!

Comment: Copy to another table, drop this, rename another to this, recreate indices and another objects. This will be more fast than OPTIMIZE. Of course the table must be locked for data change during this process.

Comment: And think about RANGE partitioning by date. DROP PARTITION removes the partition(s) with all old data almost instantly and frees disk space.

Answer (score 0):

20 single-row insers per second is modest; well within the capability of the database.  How many columns in the table?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Skip the Optimize.

Space from deleted rows will be reused by new rows.  But be sure to avoid letting the table get too full.

Split across 2 tables -- Connect two `SELECTs` with `UNION ALL` so that you can combine the data.

There are multiple solutions for big deletes.  But be cautious -- many solutions cannot be used without enough spare disk space for at least both the old and new table during the transition.

[*Big Deletes*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig)

Summary tables are also a good idea for logging data that needs to be summarized.

[*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)